# How to create a postgresql superuser without a superuser account?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, osx-mountain-lion

OK...just installed Mountain Lion. First thing I noticed was that my Postgres user account was missing from the login screen. I then verified that my postgres installation was no longer working. So I created a new postgres user account on my Mac and set all the proper permission to get the postgres server to start. It started but immediately the server shutdown. I checked the log files and it said that role "postgres" does not exist.

I can't figure out how to create this user in the db since the db won't allow me to access it without using a superuser account. I tried "createuser postgres" but got the same message, "role 'postgres' does not exist". I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: Have you tried turning authentication off in the postgresql.conf file?  Not sure if this will actually help if there aren't any DB roles, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Are you aware that the `postgres` system user is something different entirely than the `postgres` database user? They only share the same name.

Comment: [Related question with more details on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21587/3684). Seems like Apple didn't do a great job with the upgrade.

Comment: I'm aware that they are two different users. I created a system user called postgres. My problem is that the db user by the same name no longer exists for some reason. When it was working "postgres" was the db user (superuser) but now for some reason it no longer exists.

Comment: As I can't imagine that the upgrade deleted the `postgres` user from the db cluster, I am inclined to offer an alternative explanation: are you dealing with the same database cluster? Or did the upgrade install a different one, maybe?

Comment: All I can say is that the install is in the same directory so I would think that it is in the same db cluster. My install directory is not standard so I would think that this part is the same as it was originally. The data directory is in a standard place so if this is where the cluster resides then that could be a possibility.

Comment: Have a look at the related question on dba.SE that I linked to. Over there it just turned out, there are two different installations on different paths ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my problem. Somehow my postgres db user did get erased during the upgrade to mountain lion. I was able to log into the db using the same name that I use to log into the system however. Unfortunately, I found that my databases where also removed during the upgrade. I don't know why but the upgrade did effect my postgresql installation. After logging in, I found that the postgres db and the template1 db had no relations to be found. Now to piece my db back together...luckily I'm still in development mode. Note: In the future make db backups prior to upgrading system.